# Problems to log into mysql

Tags: mysql, authentication, terminal

I am very new to mysql so forgive if this might me a trivial question or something. I am working on Mac os x 10.6.

I installed phpadmin following this guide
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac-osx-10-7-lion/
and then mysql following this explanation here 
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-install-php-mysql-apache-on-os-x-10-6/

For my understanding, everything worked.

I set up a password for mysql with this command
`sudo mysql_secure_installation`

Now I want to log in mysql qith this
`mysql -u root -p[password]`

But it bounces back with this message:
`mysql -u root -p[password -e "$(curl -fsSL

https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"]
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

When I type in this line 
`mysql -u root -p`

and then my password I get this window:

[image]

That means I logged into my database right?
But why cant I log in with that other command?

I deinstalled and installed it already, but that did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's with the `[password -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"]` ?

Comment: absolutely no idea. as I wrote I am very new to mysql (coding, programming, terminal etc. in general). That came up after I typed in that line `mysql -u root -p[password]`. I replaced my actual password (the one I set up for the mysql database and had to enter in the terminal) with `password` in `[password -e "$(curl -fsSL` and `mysql -u root -p[password]`

Comment: Without an in-depth knowledge of how the mysql binary works, it looks like you're actually entering your password as: `yourpassword[go installer script here]`

Comment: Yep, it seems like something is wrong. What I dont understand is why the syntax I use is causing this and why another syntax works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that you are typing those square brackets. But those square brackets aren't part of the syntax. In the syntax diagram, the square brackets indicate that what's between them is *optional*.

To supply the password on the command line, add it immediately after the `-p`, with no space. e.g.

```
$ mysql -u root -ppassword -c
```

Another possibility is that the password includes a special character being interpreted by the shell, such as **`$`** or **`#`**, and those may need to be "escaped" by a preceding a backslash **`\`** character.

If this is working, prompting for a password, and allowing you in:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Then this should work as well:

```
$ mysql -u root -ppassword
```

Unless, again, your password contains a "metacharacter" being interpreted by the shell. I recommend you get that working first, before you start mucking with adding the `-e` option.

Comment: Thats not working neither.

do I have to be in a certain folder to enter the password or to log in or can I just to it from the folder I am in when I start the terminal?

Comment: Yep, no spaces have been added or something. copy and pasted it and changed `password` to my password I set before

Comment: Alright. I have an `!` in my password! No "I am in" Thanks man!
Any ideas btw what that github stuffs wnats there (in my error message)?

What do you mean with adding the `-e` option?

Comment: @Christoph: the `-e` option is used for specifying a statement to execute, e.g.  `mysql -u root -ppass -e "SELECT NOW();"` MySQL will execute the specified statement, and then exit immediately, rather than leaving you at the mysql command prompt.